# Sequelize set grometric point on model

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am working with sequelize/NodeJS, and I need to have a geomtric field in my model(Point), I can't figure out how to use it.

**At the moment I have this:**

```
position: {
  type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('Point'),
  allowNull: true
},
```

**but I get this error:**

```
TypeError: DataTypes.GEOMETRY is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\Desktop\FloraApp\server\models\Foto.js:22:23)
    at Sequelize.module.exports.Sequelize.import (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\Desktop\FloraApp\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:626:32)
    at C:\Users\FilipeCosta\Desktop\FloraApp\server\models\index.js:21:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\Desktop\FloraApp\server\models\index.js:20:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\FilipeCosta\Desktop\FloraApp\server\app.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Any tips?

Comment: Try fixing the typo: `GEOMETRY`

Comment: well i did a typo writing here, i had it writed correctly

Comment: Are you saying you typed the entire error message into stack overflow...? Sure.

Comment: Watch now, same error, i just said that i tried it correctly as you said the first time, then i changed got the typo and copied that